# Select-Object does transform data, but also keeps the statement in it's data

Tags: powershell

I have an array of file-string like this:

```
"./app.config@@", "./test.py@@", "./subdir/anotherfile.xsd@@"
```

Later I want to group all files belonging to the same directory. Therefore I need to cut the two '@@' signs to convert the strings to `[System.IO.FileInfo]` objects. I tried to achieve this like follows:

```
$files = $files | select {$_.Substring(0, $_.length - 2)}
```

But when I try to get the file it always also prints the expression of my select statement (The part with: `'$_.Substring(0, $_.length - 2)'`)

```
PS > $files[0]

$_.Substring(0, $_.length - 2)
------------------------------
.\App.config
```

Also when I try to get the directory from the FileInfo:

```
> ([System.IO.FileInfo]$files[0]).Directory

 Der Wert "@{[System.IO.FileInfo]$_.Substring(0, $_.length -
 2)=.\App.config}" vom Typ "Selected.System.String" kann nicht in den
 Typ "System.IO.FileInfo" konvertiert werden. In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
 + ([System.IO.FileInfo]$files[0]).directory
```

It says the string

```
"@{[System.IO.FileInfo]$_.Substring(0, $_.length -
     2)=.\App.config}"
```

Can't be converted to a `System.IO.FileInfo`

I use .Select() in LINQ to transform data to another form. Is this the wrong way to go ?

Comment: Your screenshot is pretty much unreadable. Please copy the text and post it here - formatted as code as well. Thanks.

Comment: Use `foreach` instead of `select`.

Comment: I would suggest using the trimend method as opposed to substring, this way you will only remove characters that you want to and not potentially break any string that does not have the `@@` at the end.  `$Files = $Files | Foreach {$_.TrimEnd('@@')}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand why in your example you have embedded the array with square brackets `[..]`

Use a `ForEach-Object` like this, to return a string array

```
$files = "./app.config@@", "./test.py@@", "./subdir/anotherfile.xsd@@" | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace '@+$'
    # or: $_.TrimEnd("@")
    # or: $_.Substring(0, $_.Length - 2)
}
```

Or this, which will give you an array of FileInfo objects:

```
$files = "./app.config@@", "./test.py@@", "./subdir/anotherfile.xsd@@" | ForEach-Object {
    [System.IO.FileInfo]($_ -replace '@+$')
}
```

Comment: I retrieve the initial array from another method. The brackets where just for representation of an array in my post. Thank you for you help. Can you explain what Select-Object did and why it did not work. I used Select-Object because that's what I'm used from LINQ (Select-statement to transform data)